# Show that there exists no solution with $(x, y, z)$ ∈ $\mathbb N^+ × \mathbb N^+ × \mathbb N^+$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Show that there exists no solution with $(x, y, z)$ ∈ $\mathbb N^+ × \mathbb N^+ × \mathbb N^+$ for
>
> (a) $5x^2 + 2y^2 = z^2$
>
> (b) $17x^2 + 6y^2 = z^2$

My attempt:

a) if $5x^2 + 2y^2 = z^2$ has a solution in $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$, then it has a solution in $\mathbb Z$.

mod $5$ : $2y^2 = z^2$

mod $2$ : $5x^2 = z^2$

Then in mod $5$: we have $y = 0$ mod $5$ and $z = 0$ mod $5$ iff $5|y$ in $\mathbb Z$ and $5|z$ in $\mathbb Z$

and $5^2|z^2-2y^2$ then $5^2|5x^2$ then $5|x^2$ then $5|x$

Assume that $(x,y,z)$ is a solution with $x>=0$, $y>=0$, $z>=0$ and $(x,y,z) \not= (0,0,0)$, then $\frac x5$, $\frac y5$, $\frac z5$ is a smaller positive solution. This contradicts the well-ordering principle.  Thus $5x^2 + 2y^2 = z^2$ can't have a solution $\not= (0,0,0)$

Is my attempt correct?

And do I solve part b the same as part a?

Comment: Why must $y,z = 0 \pmod{5}$? Your conclusion seems to only suggest that $2y^2 - z^2 = 0 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: because, $0^2 = 0$ (mod $5$), $1^2 = 1$ (mod $5$), $2^2=4$ (mod $5$), $3^2 = 4$ (mod $5$), $4^2=1$ (mod $5$). while $2.0^2 = 0$ (mod $5$), $2.1^2 = 2$ (mod $5$), $2.2^2 = 3$ (mod $5$), $2.3^2 = 3$ (mod $5$), $2.4^2 = 2$ (mod$5$). so the only solution is $(y,z) = (0,0)$

Comment: "If ... has a solution in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, then it has a solution in $\Bbb Z$" is neither correct, nor what you want.

Comment: but isnt there a ring isomorphism between $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z$? and if my attempt is incorrect how to solve this?

Comment: I would write that as "with $x,y,z\in\Bbb N_{>0}$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for part (b) the method is the same. Suppose that $17^2+6^2=^2$ is the solution with smallest $x \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, the equation tells us that $2x^2 \equiv z^2 \pmod{3}$, and since any square is congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo 3, we have that $x \equiv 0 \pmod{3} \Rightarrow z \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, then $9\vert x^2$ and $9\vert z^2$. So, replacing $x^2=9a^2$ and $z^2=9b^2$, we obtain 
$
17\cdot9a^2+6y^2=9b^2
$,
which gives us that $3\vert y^2 \Rightarrow 9\vert y^2$. Replacing $y^2=9\cdot c^2$, we have $17\cdot9a^2+9\cdot 6 \cdot c^2=9b^2$, and by dividing by 9, we get a new solution $17a^2+6b^2=c^2$  to the given diophantine equation, where $a<x$. So, the conclusion follows.

Comment: what conclusion follows? and is my answer for part a correct?

Comment: The conclusion is the contradiction with the well-ordering principle, since we have taken $(x,y,z)$ being a solution with the smallest $x$, and then obtained another solution $(a,b,c)$ with $a<x$.
Your solution is just missing a detail, which is to consider $(x,y,z)$ the solution with smallest $x$ or $y$ or $z$. It is not prudent to consider all being the smallest possible, since this does not happens with frequency,

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.**  For (a), $2$ is a quadratic nonresidue modulo $5$.  For (b), $17$ is a quadratic nonresidue modulo $3$.

Comment: I didnt understand what you mean

Comment: It means $t^2\equiv 2\pmod{5}$ and $t^2\equiv 17\pmod{3}$ have no integral solutions.

Comment: Could you develop your idea furthermore please?

Comment: Let $(x,y,z)$ be a primitive solution, i.e., $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$.  In (a), show that  $5\nmid y$, and therefore prove that there exists an integer $t$ such that $$yt\equiv z\pmod{5}\,.$$  Then show that $t^2\equiv 2\pmod{5}$, which is a contradiction.  In  (b), show that $3\nmid x$, and proceed similarly.